# unable to communicate with service App Engine Flex

Tags: google-app-engine

```
This post has updates at the bottom. This post will be reorganized once I find the solution.
```

I am trying to have my frontend communicate with my API. The API is a GRPC GO app and the frontend is vue.js in a Nginx container.

When going to the frontend [URL](https://view-dot-casestudy2108.ue.r.appspot.com/) I see the webpage but when I click on the button I should see some text. The text is just a static string from the API.

I enabled debug on App Engine

`gcloud app --project PROJECT-ID instances enable-debug`

When calling the API from the view container is just hangs.

`curl -L api-dot-casestudy2108.ue.r.appspot.com:8081/v1/test`

view `app.yaml`

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
service: view
automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 2
    cool_down_period_sec: 180
    cpu_utilization:
        target_utilization: 0.5
resources:
    cpu: 1
    memory_gb: 0.5
    disk_size_gb: 10
env_variables:
    API_HOST: "api-dot-casestudy2108.ue.r.appspot.com"
```

nginx upstream

```
 upstream api {
    server ${API_HOST}:8081;
 }
```

Inside the view container I can confirm the env var is set

```
/etc/nginx # echo $API_HOST
api-dot-casestudy2108.ue.r.appspot.com
```

API `app.yaml`

```
runtime: go
env: flex
service: api
automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 2
    cool_down_period_sec: 180
    cpu_utilization:
        target_utilization: 0.5
resources:
    cpu: 1
    memory_gb: 0.5
    disk_size_gb: 10
env_variables:
    HTTP_PORT: 8081
    GRPC_PORT: 8082
network:
    forwarded_ports:
      - 8081
      - 8081:8081/tcp # grpc gateway port
      - 8082
      - 8082:8082/tcp # grpc port
```

--- update 1 ---

I added a `dispatch.yaml` file and placed it with the view directly, currently the api directory doesn't contain a `dispatch.yaml`

```
dispatch:
    - # api traffic
    - url: "*/v1/*"
      service: api
      # send all other traffic to default service
    - url: "*/.*"
      service: default
```

Still no effect, but I think this is the right track. I am not sure is the file is automatically detected and applied, though.

--- update 2 ---

in the console I do not see the ports I wanted open :(

```
netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/'
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=20162 but you should be root.)
netstat: no support for `AF INET (sctp)' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF INET (sctp)' on this system.
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:20257         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:8090         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10402           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:10403        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:24231        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38535         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

--- update 3 ----

inside the default container I am able to get a successful to the view service but not the api

```
curl -L api-dot-casestudy2108.ue.r.appspot.com/v1/test
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

In the console the view's result URL is

```
https://view-dot-casestudy2108.ue.r.appspot.com/v1/test
```

which is wrong it should be

```
https://api-dot-casestudy2108.ue.r.appspot.com/v1/test
```

the views service nginx configuration has the api's URL set

```
 upstream api {
    server ${API_HOST}:8081;
 }
```

Therefore, I am not sure why it is sending the request to itself!!!

dispatch.yaml

```
# api traffic
- url: "*/v1/*"
  service: api
# view traffic
- url: "*/view/*"
  service: view
# Default service serves simple hostname request.
- url: "casestudy2108.ue.r.appspot.com/"
  service: default
```

Note: `- url: "*/view/*"` is just an arbitrary value. It might need to be `*/.*` but that doesn't seem correct.

At the moment I am not sure what to set the view and why the view is sending the request it itself??

api container

```
84a4206ae0ed   us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/casestudy2108/personal/vue-golang-grpc-base/api   "./main"                 5 days ago   Up 5 days   172.17.0.1:8080->8080/tcp, 172.17.0.1:10403->10403/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081-8082->8081-8082/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081-8082->8081-8082/udp   gaeapp
```

8081 appears to be exposed and that is where the view is trying to send the traffic.

Comment: Are you getting any error on `cloud console` or `browser`? if so, can you share?

Comment: @RoopaM I used the terminal and no there are not errors. The browser does but they are connection issues. The URL is in the post. I also updated this post. I added a dispath.yaml file. Thanks for posting!

Comment: you have `service: view` in the first `app.yaml` but that service is not dispatched in your `dispatch.yaml`

Comment: can you place `dispatch.yaml` at the root of the project folder and try?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko same issue. The repo can be found here https://github.com/drewjocham/vue-golang-grpc-base/tree/cloud_build_setup

Comment: So if the request "hangs" that means it was passed to the `api` service, but the service does not return any response. You can verify this by stopping/removing the `api` service, in which case the same request should start behaving differently. If that is the case, then the problem is within the app. Then try adding some logging on every step to see at which point it hangs.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I tired that too. There is an app engine miss configuration somewhere. In the terminal it hangs when I call the api whether it is running or not. I added update 2 as well.

Comment: Have you tried placing `dispatch.yaml` either in the root of your project directory, or in the root directory of your default service?

Comment: @RoopaM what would moving `dispatch.yaml` achieve? The only way it affects the project is when you deploy it (`gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml`), and it doesnt really matter where you deploy the file from. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko is the `dispatch.yaml`automatically detected and applied?

Comment: @Mike3355 no, `dispatch.yaml` needs to be deployed via `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml`

Comment: @Mike3355 can you please confirm you have DEPLOYED `dispatch.yaml`? Also are you sure `$API_HOST` is available within nginx? Or is it here just for brevity?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko yes I can confirm the dispatch.yaml is deployed. In the view container I can see the env var set.

Comment: ok but why do you run it on port 8081 instead of 8080? Docs explicitly mention "You must be sure that your application code is listening on 8080" https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listening_to_port_8080

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I will give it a try but it is a grpc backend app. I need to listen on two ports. One for the gateway and the other for grpc traffic.

Comment: afaik AppEngine Flex doesnt support gRPC

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko that is assame :(.. But that was the issue. port 8080

Comment: ...I'll add that as an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AppEngine Flex docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listening_to_port_8080) states:

> **Listening to port 8080**
>
> The App Engine front end will route incoming
> requests to the appropriate module on port 8080. You must be sure that
> your application code is listening on 8080.